# Was_public.jar and j2ee.jar for websphere

Tags: java, jar, websphere

I am working on a project which is needed to deployed in websphere application server (version 9.07). The was_public.jar and j2ee.jar is present in websphere's respective folders.

I want to know if there is any alternative jar which includes both was_public.jar and j2ee.jar in a single jar. Like for weblogic we have wlfullclient and it includes j2ee.jar (specifically javax i need). Can anyone help me with the information.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single jar that includes both the was_public.jar and the j2ee.jar. There are multiple j2ee.jars depending on which version of Java 2 Enterprise Edition/Java Enterprise Edition you want to build your application against so having a single one would prevent that being possible.